# Have I been hacked by a Google employee?

Tags: gmail

When using gmail this morning, I got the "Currently being used in other location" warning in the bottom right hand corner:

[image]

The details showed 2 different IP addresses accessing my account:

[image]

The IP address, 2604:ca00:119:49ec::460:46d4, is not mine.
When I looked it up on WHOIS, it says it is owned by Google.

[image]

Is my understanding correct that either

1. an employee of Google is accessing my account
   or
2. a hacker has penetrated Google security and is impersonating Google to access my account?

Comment: Take another look at the whois info ...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP misinterpreted the info provided by whois.

Comment: A whois shows that 2604:ca00:119:49ec::460:46d4 belongs to the GOOGLE-WIFI-IPV6 net.

One interpretation would be that this is a range used for a Wifi at a Google Campus (not necessarily used just by employees). However, there is also a product called Google Wifi, which seems to be (basically) a router, so I wouldn't outright discard that it would exit through one of those addresses.

Comment: @schroeder: I have taken another look at the whois info. How exactly am I misinterpreting it? I have confirmed with google that the ip address is one of theirs and they are currently investigating.

Comment: Why are you concluding that this is geographically from a Google building?

Comment: I'm closing because this basically is asking "what is 'GOOGLE-WIFI-IPV6'"? Which is not a security question. You are concerned about someone accessing your account, but first you need to confirm what that IP block is, what it is used for, and why it might show up in your logs. THEN, once you have ruled out the mundane reasons (like you have a Nest device), then there might be a security angle.

Comment: @schroeder: So, instead of closing the question, why don't you actually provide a recommendation on exactly what steps to take to do these things. My understanding is that the purpose of stack exchange is to help people who are less knowledgeable find answers from those who are more knowledgeable. Why would a Nest device be accessing my gmail?

Comment: If you asked this on the Beer and Wine StackExchange site, it would be closed for being off-topic. You've asked here because you are worried about being hacked, but the core question is off-topic here, too.

Comment: @Ángel: I do not have enough reputation to re-open this question. If you do, your assistance would be appreciated. I am happy to make whatever edits are necessary, but I do not understand exactly what schroder is asking me to do. How precisely do I go about "ruling out the mundane reasons". I don't understand how suggesting that a Nest device is accessing my gmail is a reasonable suggestion.

Comment: Please do not deface the question. Hit the "reopen" button or raise a question on https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/ to ask about options for reopening. But I'm telling you that this is not a security question. You have a piece of data that you do not understand and you are jumping to a "hacking" conclusion.

Comment: You are ignoring my precise instructions for what to do. Do not deface this question again.

Comment: @schroeder: How is this not a security question? Most reasonable human being would regard it as being a security question. What is your definition of a security question? You have made an assertion that I do not understand a piece of data but you have not done anything to prove that assertion. What is your proof? I am telling you that I have confirmed with google that this is an ip address owned by them and they are currently investigating. It is rude to simply close a question without suggesting an alternative stack exchange site to ask it.

Comment: ... Unless there is no such other site to ask... Please cool down. I have tried to explain a few times. Of course Google owns the IP, but, as I have said, that does not mean that it is from a Google ***building***. It can be from a Google device (especially since it is IPv6).

Comment: @schroeder: No re-open button is visible to me. Perhaps you need to have a certain amount of reputation to see it. I followed the suggestions for appeal here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57107/298909

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111986/discussion-between-alex-ryan-and-schroeder).